# How can I ask the Selenium-WebDriver to wait for few seconds after sendkey?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a C# Selenium-WebDriver. After send key, I want to wait few seconds. I do the following code to wait for 2 seconds.

```
public static void press(params string[] keys)
{
       foreach (string key in keys) 
       { 
          WebDriver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys(key);
          Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
       }
}
```

And I call like these:

```
press(Keys.Tab, Keys.Tab, Keys.Tab);
```

It works fine. Which one is a better way?

Comment: Why aren't you using an implicit wait for the element you need to interact with next?

Comment: Because for some tests, I have to simulate "human" way of typing characters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would avoid at all cost using something like that since it slows down tests, but I ran into a case where I didn't had other choices.

```
public void Wait(double delay, double interval)
{
    // Causes the WebDriver to wait for at least a fixed delay
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(myWebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay));
    wait.PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(interval);
    wait.Until(wd=> (DateTime.Now - now) - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay) > TimeSpan.Zero);
}
```

It's always better to observe the DOM somehow, e.g.:

```
public void Wait(Func<IWebDriver, bool> condition, double delay)
{
    var ignoredExceptions = new List<Type>() { typeof(StaleElementReferenceException) };
    var wait = new WebDriverWait(myWebDriver, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay)));
    wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(ignoredExceptions.ToArray());
    wait.Until(condition);
}

public void SelectionIsDoneDisplayingThings()
{
    Wait(driver => driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("selection")).All(x => x.Displayed), 250);
}
```

Comment: Julien, `delay` is the timeout after which the condition is deemed to have failed. Is it possible to specify `interval` at which the condition function is polled to determine whether the wait has succeeded? For ex : `Wait(Func<IWebDriver, bool> condition, double delay, double interval)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use Thread.Sleep(miliseconds) function. 
This stop your C# thread and selenium continue

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoginTest()
{
    var loginForm = driver.FindElementByXPath("//form[@id='login-form']");

    if (loginForm.Enabled)
    {
        MainPageLogin(loginForm);
        CheckLoginForm();
    }
    else
    {
        CheckLoginForm();
    }

    **Thread.Sleep(5000);**
    Assert.AreEqual(driver.Url, "https://staging.mytigo.com/en/");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void press(params string[] keys)
{
       foreach (string key in keys) 
       { 
          WebDriver.SwitchTo().ActiveElement().SendKeys(key);
          Sleep(2000);
       }
}
```

which serves the same

Comment: `Sleep()` is not a function.