# c# Selenium Webdriver -- Iterating through table rows and click button in each row

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#-3.0

I am receiving the following error on the second pass while iterate through table rows where there is an active delete button.
"Result StackTrace: OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document"

```
            IWebElement baseTable = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='approvalsGrid']/table/tbody"));
            ICollection<IWebElement> delButton = baseTable.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class = 'k-grid-remove lnkDelete']"));
            foreach (var button in delButton)
            {
                button.Click();
                WaitForAjax();
                //2nd delete button in popup
                Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text() = ' Delete']")).Click(); 
                WaitForAjax();
            }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: is this a private web page or can we view it?

Comment: This is a private page on dev server.  Have to be within network to access it.

Comment: What could possibly be happening is the 2nd iteration might find the previous delete button because it is going too fast. That would make sense why you are getting a stale element exception. You could try wrapping your click function in a try catch or put in another sleep/wait command like this before clicking the delete button (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798752/how-can-i-ask-the-selenium-webdriver-to-wait-for-few-seconds-after-sendkey)

Comment: When you click a button, the structure of the page changes, making all the rest of the buttons go stale. It would probably be better to re-lookup the first delete button with each iteration, and iterate based on you finding delete buttons vs. iterating on each button in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the collection of buttons goes stale when you click **delete** on one, so the collection is no longer usable once you delete an entry.

In this case you'll likely need to change your strategy to lookup the new delete buttons after you delete one. Something like this might work:

```
By delButtonsBy = By.XPath("//*[@class = 'k-grid-remove lnkDelete']");
bool delButtonExists = baseTable.FindElements(delButtonsBy).Count > 0;

while (delButtonExists)
{
    baseTable.FindElements(delButtonsBy)[0].Click();
    WaitForAjax();
    //2nd delete button in popup
    Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text() = ' Delete']")).Click();
    WaitForAjax();
    delButtonExists = baseTable.FindElements(delButtonsBy).Count > 0;
}
```

This is more expensive because you have to look up the collection over an over, but you'll have to do that anyway to get the first element because the page structure changes and the collection is out of date every time you delete one.

You could alter this further to just get the first element to check against instead of the entire collection which might improve performance slightly, but it should be pretty quick either way unless you're talking about a very large amount of buttons.

Comment: This code is a bit magical. It works! 
I found this code was a little better at finding the table itself:
IWebElement tableElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("resultTableHeader"));